# Child widget will be missing when QMainWindow is Non-Maximized

Tags: qt, window, qwidget

```
ui->setupUi(this);
setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);//Qt::WindowFullScreen;

QWidget *pStateInfosBar = new StateInfosBar(this);
//pStateInfosBar->show();
QRect rcSibWannaGeometry(QApplication::desktop()->width() - 250,
                         style()->PixelMetric::PM_TitleBarHeight, 250,
                         height());
pStateInfosBar->setGeometry(rcSibWannaGeometry);
```

My codes as shown above.But the **pStateInfosBar** will be missing when his parent window non-maximized, and it will reappear when parent is maximized.Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initialization of the QRect, you're setting the x coordinate of pStateInfosBar to your screen's width - 250. As a result, if your window's width is less than your screen's width - 250, the widget will be outside the window.

Maybe you were looking for `this->width() - 250` instead of `QApplication::desktop()->width() - 250`

Comment: You refer to Window is which? **QApplication::desktop()->width()** return my screen's width,it is fixed.And based on what you said, _less than_  widget should show away from broder of screen even more--to the middle.

Comment: @Crawl.W When I say "Window," I mean the form.

setGeometry is relative to the window , not the screen. So if the window is 50px from the top of the screen, and a widget's geometry is (20, 20, 50, 50) the widget will be 20px from the top of the window and 20px from the left of the window.

Comment: Oh,yup.I dont understand **Geometry**before.Thanks.

Comment: By the way,`this->height()` return value is not window's height when maximized,this's?

Comment: @Crawl.W this->height() should return the window's height, even when maximised.

Comment: But I got value returned by whether it is `height()` or `frameGeometry().height()` is smaller than maximized window's height.I do this in window's constructor.

Comment: @Crawl.W ```this->height()``` returns the window's height, minus any frames that the system puts on it - for example, the title bar of the window.

Comment: Yes,I know it.I wanna the working area's height,which is `height()`-excluding any frames.But 'frameGeometry().height()'  is even smaller than maximized work area's height.If I set a constant,that's effective.

Comment: resulting value is original value before maximized

Comment: I got it.`setWindowState()` will be effective until `show()` is called..